# Looking to convert information from a file into a hash Ruby

Tags: ruby

Hello I have been doing some research for sometime on this particular project I have been working on and I am at a loss. What I am looking to do is use information from a file and convert that to a hash using some of those components for my key. Within the file I have:1,Foo,20,Smith,40,John,55

An example of what I am looking for  I am looking for an output like so        `{1 =>[Foo,20], 2 =>[Smith,40] 3 => [John,55]}`

Here is what I got.

```
h = {}

people_file = File.open("people.txt")  # I am only looking to read here.
until people_file.eof?
  i = products_file.gets.chomp.split(",")
end
people_file.close
```

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "throw it into my array" or "have the hash around my array". That there are no answers two hours after the question was posted suggests others share my lack of understanding. You need to be precise. Showing the Ruby object you want returned for your example would help. Also, does the file contain the string `"1,Foo,20 2,Smith,40 3,John,55"` and nothing more?

Comment: I see my post wasn't properly portrayed in someways 1,Foo,20,Smith,40,John,55 is the full string within that file. What I mean by throwing this into a hash / array. I am looking for an output like so{1  =>[Foo,20], 2 =>[Smith,40] 3 => [John,55]}. Thanks for your response I hope this clarification is helpful.

Comment: "I am at a loss." is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: You say you want the return value to be `{1=>[Foo,20], 2=>[Smith,40] 3=>[John,55]}`. `Foo` is not a Ruby object. I assume you mean `"Foo"` (etc.). Where you write `1 =>[Foo,20]`, `1` is an integer, not a string. That's fine, but since you omitted quotes around `Foo` we can't be sure you don't mean it to be  `"1"`. What is the significance `'1"` at the beginning of the string? If it were `"5,Foo,20,Smith,40,John,55"` those of us giving answers would have assumed the return value should be `{5=>["Foo",20], 6 =>["Smith",40] 7 => ["John",55]}`, but you say nothing about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FName = 'test'
str = "1,Foo,20,Smith, 40,John,55"
File.write(FName, str)
  #=> 26 

base, *arr = File.read(FName).
                  split(/\s*,\s*/)
enum = (base.to_i).step
arr.each_slice(2).
    with_object({}) {|pair,h| h[enum.next]=pair}
  #=> {1=>["Foo", "20"], 2=>["Smith", "40"],
  #    3=>["John", "55"]}
```

The steps are as follows.

```
s = File.read(FName)
  #=> "1,Foo,20,Smith, 40,John,55" 
base, *arr = s.split(/\s*,\s*/)
  #=> ["1", "Foo", "20", "Smith", "40", "John", "55"] 
base 
  #=> "1" 
arr
  #=> ["Foo", "20", "Smith", "40", "John", "55"] 
a = base.to_i
  #=> 1
```

I assume the keys are to be sequential integers beginning with `a #=> 1`.

```
enum = a.step
  #=> (1.step)
enum.next
  #=> 1      
enum.next
  #=> 2
enum.next
  #=> 3
```

Continuing,

```
enum = a.step
b = arr.each_slice(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["Foo", "20", "Smith", "40", "John", "55"]:each_slice(2)>
```

Note I needed to redefine `enum` (or execute `enum.rewind`) to reinitialize it. We can see the elements that will be generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array.

```
b.to_a
  #=> [["Foo", "20"], ["Smith", "40"], ["John", "55"]]
```

Continuing,

```
c = b.with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: ["Foo", "20", "Smith", "40", "John", "55"]
  #     :each_slice(2)>:with_object({})>
c.to_a
  #=> [[["Foo", "20"], {}], [["Smith", "40"], {}], [["John", "55"], {}]]
```

The now-empty hashes will be constructed as calculations progress.

```
c.each {|pair,h| h[enum.next]=pair}
  #=> {1=>["Foo", "20"], 2=>["Smith", "40"], 3=>["John", "55"]}
```

To see how the last step is performed, `each` initially directs the enumerator `c` to generate the first value, which it passes to the block. The block variables are assigned to that value, and the block calculation is performed.

```
enum = a.step
b = arr.each_slice(2)
c = b.with_object({})

pair, h = c.next
  #=> [["Foo", "20"], {}] 
pair
  #=> ["Foo", "20"] 
h #=> {} 
h[enum.next]=pair
  #=> ["Foo", "20"]
```

Now,

```
h#=> {1=>["Foo", "20"]}
```

The calculations are similar for the remaining two elements generated by the enumerator `c`.

See [IO::write](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html#method-c-write), [IO::read](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html#method-c-read), [Numeric#step](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Numeric.html#method-i-step), [Enumerable#each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice), [Enumerator#with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object), [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) and [Enumerator#rewind](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-rewind). `write` and `read` respond to `File` because `File` is a subclass of `IO` (`File.superclass #=> IO`). `split`'s argument, the regular expression, `/\s*,\s*/`, causes the string to be split on commas together with any spaces that surround the commas. Converting `[["Foo", "20"], {}]` to `pair` and `h` is a product of [Array Decompostion](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition).